# Many to many relationship in Entity Framework - results in “An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker”

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many, entity-framework-6

I am trying to setup a classic "Article and Categories" scenario in Entity Framework. To do this, I have these classes:

```
public class RichContent : BaseIdEntity
{
    public string Headline { get; set; }

    public virtual List<RichContentCategory.RichContentCategory> Categories { get; set; }


    public RichContent()
    {
        Categories = new List<RichContentCategory.RichContentCategory>();
    }
}
```

And my categories:

```
public class RichContentCategory : BaseIdEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<RichContent.RichContent> RichContents { get; set; }

    public RichContentCategory()
    {
        this.RichContents = new List<RichContent.RichContent>();
    }
}
```

Which is setup with this:

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<RichContent>()
                   .HasMany<RichContentCategory>(s => s.Categories)
                   .WithMany(c => c.RichContents)
                   .Map(cs =>
                   {
                       cs.MapLeftKey("RichContentRefId");
                       cs.MapRightKey("RichContentCategoryId");
                       cs.ToTable("RichContentCategoryPlacement");
                   });
```

Now, when I run this and add a category like the following and saves:

```
   item.Categories.Add(richContentCategory);
```

I get the following error at `_db.RichContent.Add(content);` inside my CREATE method:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.
```

I could understand the underlying problem is how I need to use same Context. However, I inject the context using Ninject, and my service that creates looks like this:

```
 public class RichContentService : IRichContentService
    {
        private readonly Context _db;

        public RichContentService(Context db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public RichContent Create(RichContent content)
        {
            _db.RichContent.Add(content);

            _db.SaveChanges();

            return GetById(content.Id);
        }
}
```

So my question is basically - how do you add categories to an article like in this case?

EDIT:

My code that runs is an importer that has this:

```
 finally
                {
                    if (needToCreate)
                    {
                        var result = Create(richContent);
                        logger.Info("Created a new rich-content page");
                    }
                }
```

And the Create() method:

```
 public RichContent Create(RichContent content)
        {
            PerformValidation(content);

            _db.RichContent.Add(content);
            _db.SaveChanges();

            return GetById(content.Id);
        }
```

And the input to the CREATE method:

```
 var item = new RichContent()
            {
                WordpressId = dto.id,
                DateCreated = dto.date,
                Slug = dto.slug,
                Content = dto.content,
                Headline = dto.title,
                DateModified = dto.modified,

            };

            if (dto.custom_fields.category_type != null && dto.custom_fields.category_type.Any() &&
               !string.IsNullOrEmpty(dto.custom_fields.category_type[0]))
            {
                var categories = _richContentCategoryService.GetBySpecification(new RichContentCategorySpecification()
                {
                    Take = Int32.MaxValue
                });

                var list = dto.custom_fields.category_type[0];
                foreach (var richContentCategory in categories)
                {

                    if (list.Contains(richContentCategory.WordpressName))
                    {
                        item.Categories.Add(richContentCategory);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (dto.custom_fields.featured != null)
            {
                item.Featured = dto.custom_fields.featured.Any(c => c == "1");
            }

            if (dto.custom_fields.area != null)
            {
                item.Area = dto.custom_fields.area.Any(c => c == "1");

                if (item.Area)
                {
                    var children = ConvertWordpressDtos(dto.children);
                    foreach (var child in children.Where(c=>c.Area))
                    {

                        child.Slug = string.Format("{0}/{1}", item.Slug, child.Slug);
                        item.Children.Add(child);
                    }
                }


            }
```

Comment: Where did you get `RichContent` from? This error may happen if you get an entity from another context.

Comment: @AlexSikilinda I have a small importer that iterates a lot of nodes from a different system, and then makes a new resource (new RichContent()) and call the CREATE method

Comment: Can you add the code when you construct `RichContent` and pass it to `Create`?

Comment: @AlexSikilinda So I create the instance inside the CREATE method, instead of outside? 
In theory, yes. I just think it's a bit bad design and different from how rest of solution work. But it should work? :-)

Comment: Could you provide the code of `(new RichContent()) and call the CREATE`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The problem**

The exception clearly indicates that when you save a new `RichContent` an entity associated with the `RichContent` is tracked by another Entity Framework context. In your particular case the entity is `RichContentCategory` that is returned from `_richContentCategoryService.GetBySpecification`:

```
var categories = _richContentCategoryService.GetBySpecification(new RichContentCategorySpecification()
{
    Take = Int32.MaxValue
});

var list = dto.custom_fields.category_type[0];
foreach (var richContentCategory in categories)
{
    if (list.Contains(richContentCategory.WordpressName))
    {
        item.Categories.Add(richContentCategory);
    }
}
```

**How to fix**

The best option here is to manage to use the same context for all object that are used in this scenario. To achieve this you can add the `item` to categories and than use `_richContentCategoryService` to save categories:

```
var categories = _richContentCategoryService.GetBySpecification(new RichContentCategorySpecification()
{
    Take = Int32.MaxValue
});

var list = dto.custom_fields.category_type[0];
foreach (var richContentCategory in categories)
{
    if (list.Contains(richContentCategory.WordpressName))
    {
        richContentCategory.RichContents.Add(item);
    }
}

// Save updated categories somehow, using "_richContentCategoryService" object
_richContentCategoryService.Save(categories);
```

If you are not able to do it you can try doing smth like this:

```
foreach (var richContentCategory in categories)
{
    if (list.Contains(richContentCategory.WordpressName))
    {
        item.Categories.Add(new RichContentCategory { Id = richContentCategory.Id});
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! You're totally right. Not only did it work, you also provided a great explaination :) Thanks.
I'll award bounty when I can (~4 hours).